# Creating a bijection for edges on a graph?

Tags: graph-theory, induction

[image]

I am really really confused on this question. How do I create a bijection from the edges on the graph to the vertices? How does this prove en=n choose 2? I'm super lost and any help is super greatly appreciated. thanks!

Comment: "*How do I create a bijection from the edges on the graph to the vertices*"  You don't.  There aren't the same number of edges as vertices in most cases.  You are meant to make a bijection from the set of edges to something else.  What do you know about binomial coefficients?  Given that the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{2}$ counts the number of subsets of size two from an $n$-element set, and given that an edge is a two-element subset of the set of vertices, can you continue?

Comment: As for the inductive proof, structure it as you do every other induction proof that you should have seen up to this point.  Now... given a complete graph on $n+1$ vertices, consider the induced subgraph on only the first $n$ vertices and how many edges are there (*which we know according to our induction hypothesis*), then consider what happens if you return the $n+1$'st vertex and the edges that go along with it.

Comment: so essentially there exists a bijection from the edges of graph with n vertices to (2) since edges are subsets of size 2 from an n-element set? and since this is a bijection they have the same size so then they are equal?